# Weird allowed behaivor when casting a string to an array

Tags: php

I've been asked this question on the interview, why **this code works and outputs 12245**

```
$a = '12345';

$a[$a[1]] = '2';

echo $a; // 12245
```

So far, I've been trying to comprehend that myself, but still with no luck.

Since `$a` is a string, and has not been declared as *array*, then how is that even possible that `$a` has an `index = 1`? And that index is being substituted by another non-existing index! Couldn't someone please explain that?

Comment: You can't print an array with `echo`.

Comment: Strings can be referenced like arrays.  The "indexes" are the characters.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the answer to me

Comment: @bad_boy: That is *exactly* the answer here.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP strings can be accessed like arrays using `[]`.  The "indexes" in this case are the characters of the string.  There is no casting going on.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

So, with `$a = '12345';`, that means `$a[1]` is `'2'`.  So, doing `$a[$a[1]]` is like doing `$a['2']` (the string `'2'` is converted to an int by PHP).

What's happening is the character at index `2` (the 3rd character) is being replaced with a `2`.  Thus creating `'12245'`.

Answer (score 3):

As strings can be referenced like arrays then:

1. `$a[1] is '2' // starting from zero`
2. `$a[$a[1]]` is `$a[2]` which is currently `3` `// still starting from zero`
3. Setting `$a[2]` to `2` gives us exactly `12245`